# Android mass storage folder on an MK802 II?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I'm using an MK802 Mini PC running stock Android ICS.
It has **no** external micro-sd card inserted.

While connected to my PC, the device is showing as a mass storage device - which allows me to copy files to it.  So far so good.

Problem is, I can't seem to find these files from with in the device (using SSH from my PC or directly from the device's File Explorer).  It's as if the directory structure (the one mapped as 'G' on my PC) does not exist on the device.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the device rooted? Try to install [Total Commander for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander&hl=nl), you can try to navigate to your storage folder and you will see at the upper left corner the filepath (e.g. '/sdcard0' or '/sdcard1')

Comment: Thanks ObAt.  It's an MK802 II so it's already rooted.  I installed TC  as you suggested but whenever I try to access a folder that should be in sdcard (such as mnt/sdcard/DCIM or mnt/sdcard/Download) I get a 'Can't Access' error message.  How is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure your sdcard is located at /mnt/sdcard?

Comment: The /mnt folder has an 'sdcard' subfolder, and an 'extsd' subfolder.   Since there is no SD card installed, the extsd folder is empty.  I assumed the rest of the device's storage is at 'sdcard' but there's nothing there.  Just to clarify - I'm looking for the folder that maps to a Windows drive once I connect the device to the PC.  I can see the files from Windows Explorer, but can't find them from the Android's interface...

Comment: Copy a file to your device named 'test123abc' and try to search it with Total Commander :)

Comment: That's exactly what I did.  The MK802 dongle is mapped to Windows drive F:\.  F now contains a couple of files and folders.  I tried looking for them using TC for I get 'Function Not Supported'.  WTF?

Comment: Figured it out.  Turns out I needed to set the device's Storage Setting to MTP (Media Device).  Now both internal and external storage are visible.  Thanks a lot for your help.